# Empty parameter is not Null in function

Tags: function, powershell, if-statement

Given this basic function:

```
Function TestFunction {
    Param ( [int]$Par1, [string]$Par2, [string]$Par3 )
    If ($Par1 -ne $Null) { Write-Output "Par1 = $Par1" }
    If ($Par2 -ne $Null -or $Par2 -ne '') { Write-Output "Par2 = $Par2" }
    If ($Par3 -ne $Null) { Write-Output "Par3 = $Par3" }
}
TestFunction -Par1 1 -Par3 'par3'
```

...the output is:

```
Par1 = 1
Par2 = 
Par3 = par3
```

Even though I didn't pass anything into the `$Par2` variable, it still isn't Null or empty. What happened, and how can I rewrite the statement so that the second If-statement evaluates as False and the script-block does not get executed?

(I added the `-or $Par2 -ne ''` just to test, it behaves the same with and without it.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a logic error in your program:  `$Par2` will *always* be not equal to `$null` **or** not equal to `''`.

To fix the logic, you should use `-and` instead of `-or` here:

```powershell
If ($Par2 -ne $Null -and $Par2 -ne '') { Write-Output "Par2 = $Par2" }
```

However, because you casted the `$Par2` argument to a string in the function's argument list:

```powershell
Param ( [int]$Par1, [string]$Par2, [string]$Par3 )
                    ^^^^^^^^
```

the check for `$Par2 -ne $Null` is unnecessary since `$Par2` will always be of type string (if you do not give it a value, it will be assigned to `''`).  So, you should actually write:

```powershell
If ($Par2 -ne '') { Write-Output "Par2 = $Par2" }
```

Or, because `''` evaluates to false, you might just do:

```powershell
If ($Par2) { Write-Output "Par2 = $Par2" }
```

Comment: That was fast. But what is actually IN `$Par2`? If I pass a value into it, `$Par2 -ne $Null` will be true.
But if I pass nothing into it `$Par2 -ne $Null` should be false and should not be executed, right?
And yet, it does...

Comment: See my edit.  `$Par2` will always be a string because you casted it to one in the function's argument list.  Also, for future, you can get the type of any variable using the `GetType` method:  `$Par2.GetType()`.  This will greatly aid in debugging.

Comment: So, because I casted it in the parameter-block, it will always exist and therefor never be null? Even if I were to change the default value into null (`[string]$Par2 = $Null`)?  
And an integer will always be 0? So if I were to pass nothing into `$par1`, then `If ($Par1)` will be true because it contains 0?  
So in trying to write a better script by casting the variable-types, I actually made it more difficult for myself.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  `$Par2` will never be `$null` because you casted it to a string.  Even if you do `[string]$Par2 = $Null`, it will still be assigned to `''` (you can test this using `$Par2.GetType()`).  And yes, `[int]$Par1 = $Null` will make `$Par1` become `0`.   However, `If ($Par1)` will not be true because `0` evaluates to false in a boolean context (all other numbers evaluate to true).

Comment: I think I get it, thank you. You saved me from a headache. For completeness in this thread, I just discovered `[string]$Par2 = [System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString]::Value` to turn a string into null after all, now that I have an idea what to Google for. Although that doesn't work for integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that (check if $variablename has $null as value):

`if (!$variablename) { Write-Host "variable is null" }`

And  if you wanna check if $variablename has any value except $null:

`if ($variablename) { Write-Host "variable is NOT null" }`